# Use SharedPreference to define drawable resources

Tags: java, android, android-background

I have a few drawables:

```
R.drawable.pres01
R.drawable.pres02
R.drawable.pres03
```

I want to use `SharedPreference` to display the proper drawable:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String someId;
ImageView ivPresident;
int inAdd;

prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("pNum", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

someId = prefs.getString("presNum", "");
inAdd = Integer.parseInt(someId);

ivPresident = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewPresident);
```

I converted the String to Integer, now how do I set the image source of `ivPresident` to the number based on the saved string.

So for example:

if `someId` is `01` the drawable for `ivPresident` is `R.drawable.pres01`

if `someId` is `02` the drawable for `ivPresident` is `R.drawable.pres02`

if `someId` is `03` the drawable for `ivPresident` is `R.drawable.pres03`

I tried the following but did not work:

```
ivPresident.setBackground(R.drawable.pres + inAdd);
```

How do I fix the code to achieve it?

Comment: seems to me you are creating unnecessary work for yourself when all you have to do to access it is use `getResources()`

Comment: I am not sending `R.drawable.pres01` I am only sending `01`. Should I send the entire string? Will it make it easy?

Comment: what is wrong with just using it the normal way ie. `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pres01);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

`Resources.getIdentifier(String name...)`

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Build the string the way you are trying now.

EDIT:

```
String someId = prefs.getString("presNum", "");
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("pres0" + someId, "drawable", getPackageName())
ivPresident.setBackgroundResource(id);
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to give me an example with what I provided?

Comment: I am not sending R.drawable.pres01 I am only sending 01. Should I send the entire string? Will it make it easy?

Comment: setBackground() does not or no longer takes an int. Use setBackgroundResource(int)